# Neo4j Graph display

Tags: java, neo4j

I am new with the neo4j graphic database. Could anyone help me on how to display the neo4j Graph in a Java JFrame ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, neo4j is a database, so I don't think you'll find straightforward ways to render a graph in a swing component without doing some manual tasks yourself, like first generating an image which is then rendered in a JPanel etc.

Maybe you could have a look [here](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize) and get some ideas from where to start.